# Project Deployment

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I have developed a C# windows form application.

How should i create an .exe file in Visual Studio 2008 so that it can be installed in other machines?

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3315944/deploy-net-c-exe-application-on-desktops).

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just copy the EXE onto their computer? As long as they've already got the right version of .NET installed and you're not using any third-party dependencies, it should just run.

Answer (score 3):

A Simple ["Setup and Deployment"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx3b589t%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) project would work for most cases.  [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) if you want to learn a powerful installer, or any of the other OSS installers out there.  You could even zip up your release dir if that is all you needed and didn't want the app in the start menu or any such thing.  Your question is somewhat vague.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at ClickOnce deployment. There's a video here: http://windowsclient.net/learn/video.aspx?v=14105

If you just want the .exe file, it is located in the bin\debug or bin\release folder of your project's directory depending on the current configuration setting.

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to use [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28VS.80%29.aspx) technology to deploy your application.  There are details in this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365431/is-clickonce-still-the-way-to-go-for-winform-app-deployment). But here is an excerpt:

Directly from the words of MS, ClickOnce overcomes three issues in deployment:

- Difficulties in updating
  applications. With Microsoft Windows
  Installer deployment, whenever an
  application is updated, the user must
  reinstall the entire application;
  with ClickOnce deployment, you can
  provide updates automatically. Only
  those portions of the application
  that have changed are downloaded,
  then the full, updated application is
  reinstalled from a new side-by-side
  folder.
- Impact to the user's computer. With
  Windows Installer deployment,
  applications often rely on shared
  components, with the potential for
  versioning conflicts; with ClickOnce
  deployment, each application is
  self-contained and cannot interfere
  with other applications.
- Security permissions. Windows
  Installer deployment requires
  administrative permissions and allows
  only limited user installation;
  ClickOnce deployment allows
  non-administrative users to install
  and grants only those Code Access
  Security permissions necessary for
  the application.