# Desktop applicaton not opening after installation in client system

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer

I am currently working with visual studio 2017 with 4.6.1 .net framework. I created setup file for my desktop application the setup installs and runs perfectly in my system. The issue is that the setup installs successfully in other computers but the application not getting opened.

**edit**

Downloaded .net framework in client system but still same issue occurs.

**edit 2**

I ran a dependency scan using Dependency walker. It said there were a bunch of files the system could not find - error opening file. The system cannot find the files specified.

```
  API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-RUNTIME-L1-1-0.DLL
  API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ERROR-L1-1-0.DLL
  API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-L1-1-0.DLL
  API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ROBUFFER-L1-1-0.DLL
  API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL
  API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-SCALING-L1-1-1.DLL
  DCOMP.DLL
  IESHIMS.DLL
```

Also, there was an error with modules with an x86 type found - including the setup.exe - but I am unaware how this happened. I have selected 64 wherever I saw the option listed. Please find the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jyf6n.jpg). If this is indeed the issue, how do I solve this?

Comment: check the Windows Event Log, anything about .Net Framework?

Comment: On first glance this could be the **Visual C++ runtime**? A very common problem. Though you specify C#, I guess you could have C++ components. What version of Visual Studio do you use to compile your project? [The latest supported Visual C++ downloads](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads). Look in Add / Remove Programs on machines that work and don't work respectively for what version of the runtime that is installed? Finally: I presume you don't install debug versions of your binaries? Runtimes for these require developer PC debug dlls.

Comment: For the record, those dependencies are API-Sets. [Please see attempted explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53509976/129130). Did you try to scan dependencies with the newer [Dependencies.exe](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies/releases)? It is a modern rewrite of Dependency Walker capable of handling API-Set resolution. It has a few quirks as of yet though. [The peview.exe file included with the tool you can safely delete for safety](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies/issues/26). Not malware as such, but can cause some drama as "unwanted software" detected by anti-virus.

Answer (score 2):

> ***Application Launch Problems***: Here is a short version: [WPF application crashes when I launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56499648/wpf-application-crashes-when-i-launch/56500151#56500151). [Chattier version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48651252/exe-file-is-not-working/48654444#48654444). Nice one from Martin Prikryl: [Application does not work when installed with Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44333839/application-does-not-work-when-installed-with-inno-setup)

---

***Logs***: Always check all **event logs**, **application logs** and **MSI logs** - if available. Just to mention it. [Maybe try to attach debugger for testing as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51939079/which-winform-project-files-should-be-packed-up-into-the-installer/51940598#51940598) - provided the application gets off the ground at all. Then step through code.

***The Usual Culprits***: You probably just **`lack a runtime`** ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68762945/129130)), have a **`bitness problem`** (32/64-bit) or **`insufficient permissions / privileges`**, or **`configuration errors`** (`ini`, `xml`, `registry`, `etc...`).

[***To summarize***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49623588/windows-application-startup-error-exception-code-0xe0434352/49637913#49637913) - torpedos, full spread below - nothing too dumb not to mention :-):

---

> ***Missing Runtimes***: First, always check for missing runtimes. For example: **`.Net`**, **`.Net Core`**, **`Java`**, **`Silverlight`**,
> **`Direct X`** (used even for applications now), **`VC++ Runtime`**, **`MS-XML`** (legacy), **`etc...`**. Remember that they come in different versions and some can not co-exist on the box whilst others
> can run side-by-side.

---

> ***Error Code***: Looking up error codes and exception messages.
>
> - ["The Magic Number Database"](https://www.magnumdb.com/) - online lookup.
> - [Checking Error Codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52572537/msiexec-returns-negative-number/52573312#52573312) - several tools and approaches.

---

> ***Debugging Tools***: [Some information on debugging tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55413716/loadlibrary-failed-with-error-code-126-if-app-started-from-installation-option#comment97571055_55413716).

> - [Tools to debug dependency issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51939079/which-winform-project-files-should-be-packed-up-into-the-installer) - `ProcMon.exe`, `VS`, `Dependency Walker`, `etc...`
> - [COM dependency errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56121116/129130)
> - Essential service debugging tools:
>
>   - **`Event Viewer`**, **`Task Manager`**, **`Services.msc`**
>   - [**`Process Explorer`**](https://www.coretechnologies.com/blog/windows-services/essential-tools-for-windows-services-process-explorer/), [**`NET command`**](https://www.coretechnologies.com/blog/windows-services/essential-tools-for-windows-services-net-command/), [**`SC.exe`**](https://www.coretechnologies.com/blog/windows-services/essential-tools-windows-services-sc-exe/)
> - [Windows Services Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)](https://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html)

---

> [***ProcMon.exe***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon): The tool of the trade. The one-size-fits-all
> tool. The bee's knees, the topper-most, the quantum leap, the cat's
> pajamas (yes, it is a Top Gear Hamster allusion). It can be a challenge to use it effectively, but it is the
> best general-purpose debugging tool that is free.
>
> - [Quick, Rudimentary Sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47746076/registering-a-cpp-dll-into-com-after-installation-using-wix-msi-installer/47792474#47792474)
> - [Hanselman's longer video sample](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pjKNx41Ubxw)

---

***Other Ideas***:

1. **Configuration Settings**?

   - **Dev-box sins**: Hard coded references? Test Servers / UAT links?
   - **Manifests**, **INI files** and **XMLfiles**?
   - **Registry settings**? HKLM / HKCU
   - **Connection strings**. See Authentication & Authorization section below as well.
2. Platform & **Bitness**? (ARM, Intel 32 / 64, etc...).

   - Very common to read from wrong registry hive (**the** classic time waster):

     - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\MyApp\MySettings` (32-bit)
     - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyApp\MySettings` (64-bit)
3. **Prerequisites & [Dependencies](http://www.dependencywalker.com/help/html/dependency_types.htm)**?

   - [**On the topic of dependency scanning and debugging**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51939079/which-winform-project-files-should-be-packed-up-into-the-installer/51940598#51940598).
   - Dependency Walker: [**Types of dependencies**](http://www.dependencywalker.com/help/html/dependency_types.htm).
   - Does [***Fuslogvw.exe***](https://www.magnumdb.com/) tell you anything? (.NET assembly binding failures for a .NET application). [**How the Runtime Locates Assemblies**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/how-the-runtime-locates-assemblies)
   - Quick check: Visual Studio modules view
4. **Missing / Broken Registration** (indirect dependencies)

   - Missing COM, COM Interop (regasm.exe), registrationless COM (manifest based)

     - [Calling a .NET Component from a COM Component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973802.aspx)
     - [Calling COM Components from .NET Clients](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973800.aspx)
   - Broken Side-By-Side Win32 Assembly Manifest (obscure, can be caused by sloppy corporate application repackaging, may strike seemingly random PCs)
   - GAC installation?

     - [Two GACs exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660355/net-4-0-has-a-new-gac-why).
     - [GAC / WinSxS Commit Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55088813/129130): GAC / WinSXS files don't get installed into the GAC until the commit phase which is after StartServices.
5. **Permissions & Privilege**? - local - [**ACL permissions**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53087656/setup-cannot-set-correct-folder-permission-for-programdata-myfirm-myapp-on-win/53108569#53108569) and [**NT privileges**](https://ss64.com/nt/ntrights.html)?

   - [ProcMon.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon)
   - ***Resolving Permission Denied***:

     - [System.UnauthorizedAccessException while running .exe under program files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50587622/system-unauthorizedaccessexception-while-running-exe-under-program-files/50588465#50588465)
     - [WiX after installation my exe file doesn't work by double click, only run as administrator work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52403766/wix-after-installation-my-exe-file-doesnt-work-by-double-click-only-run-as-adm/52407583#52407583)
6. **Authentication / Authorization** - network related

   - Local user, domain user, Active Directory: group membership, group policy, etc...
   - Launching User: User profile issues? Maybe try with another user logged on where it fails?
   - **Authentication Mode**: Windows Authentication. SQL Server  Authentication, etc...
7. **General Network & Proxy issues**? (proxies, WINS, DNS and all the complexities involved in networking. UNC paths reachable?)
8. **Licensing**? (conceivably related to hardware dongles and drivers)
9. **Security software interference**? (software / hardware firewall, anti-virus, encryption tools and suites, etc...)
10. OS version or edition? ([Windows 7 problems](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/65))
11. Localization? Non-English systems?
12. Drivers?
13. Hardware?
14. Encoding?
15. System corruption? (wrong time, disk errors, file and path names are too long, disk full, "wrong something")
16. Target Machine Nature? Virtuals? SOE? Are the target machines real machines? Test machines?
17. Locking / Blocking / In-Use files and registry keys?
18. Malware? Can cause practically anything in terms of problems.

---

***Links***:

- [WiX Toolset PermissionEx Problem - App Does Not Run After Installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53354907/wix-toolset-permissionex-problem-app-does-not-run-after-installation/53364536#53364536)
- **[EXE file is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48651252/exe-file-is-not-working/48654444#48654444)**

Comment: Added a couple of more bullet points and details. You can see changes by clicking "edited x hours / minutes ago" (if available).

Comment: Another dumb one that got me once is that I had a logger that was writing to a folder called 'logs' in the same directory as my application exe. This worked just fine when debugging in VS, but on install into C:\ProgramFiles\... the log file was suddenly inaccessible (permissions problem) and the application would silently fail.

Comment: Yes, I have seen that many times. It is a variant of issue 5 above "permission issues".

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the 4.6.1 .net framework is installed on the client system.Because the application requires .net frame work installed on the computer

Comment: why particularly 4.6.1 only? please provide reference also why .net framework required to run winform application so that OP can understand

Answer (score 0):

To successfully deploy an application, you must also deploy all components that are referenced by the application.[View the Deployment Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3315944/deploy-net-c-exe-application-on-desktops)

Users might need administrative permissions or similar user permissions on the computer to install bootstrapped components. For ClickOnce applications, this means that the user might need administrative permissions to install the application regardless of the security level specified by the application. After the application is installed, the user can run the application without administrative permissions.

I am assuming you and your client are running install and application run as Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Possible root cause:

1. System prerequisite is not meet, you should check all dependencies is ready on the target client system, or add the prerequisite to your installation guide
2. Privilege issues, you might copy files or change registry locally with administrator rights, but the client is not. If so, you need change files to "C:\Users{username}\AppData\Roaming" or install with administrator privilege on the client system.

In such a situation, app possibly crashed in client system:

1. Check your application log if any errors
2. Check windows Log if any errors
3. Dump system info using WinDbg.exe and debug it

Answer (score -1):

I also faced that kind of problem before.
Just try to install another location not inside the program file of C:\ Drive. You may choose different drive or you may install in C drive also but not inside the program files.